# Are these Apparmor profiles unnecessary?

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome, chromium, apparmor

I'm running Lubuntu 12.10. I've installed `apparmor-profiles`. I uninstalled the Chromium browser have the latest Chrome stable in its place.
Now I'm trying to learn a little about Apparmor profiles. When I enter `sudo aa-status` in a terminal, I see, in part, the following:

```
[06:58 PM] ~ $ sudo aa-status  
[sudo] password for vasa1:   
apparmor module is loaded.  
43 profiles are loaded.  
20 profiles are in enforce mode.  
...
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//browser_java  
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//browser_openjdk  
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//sanitized_helper  
...
```

and, a little further down:

```
23 profiles are in complain mode.
...
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser  
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//chromium_browser_sandbox  
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//xdgsettings  
...
```

My question is this: why do I have entries relating to the Chromium browser showing up? Are they of any use?

Will they go away if I delete just `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser`? And is it benefical in anyway to delete that profile (assuming I have no intention of installing the Chromium browser in future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No use without chromium installed, but no benefit to delete them either.